# How do i select items from a table(id) to display matched id from another table?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables in my db, 1 for Collabs and 1 for Projects

I want when I view a project, to display the collabs based on that project (if i press view on a project for example project with id = 10, to display all Collabs for the project that is id 10).

For Collabs table I have `id_project` that is wanted to be in relationship with `id` from Project table, so when I insert a new collab in my Collabs table it takes the id from the project I inserted.

For now, this is how I display the collabs, and i display them all for all projects but I don't want that.

[image: img]

```
@forelse ($istoric as $istProj)
         <div class="mb-3">
         <table class='table'>
            <tr class="table-row-heads">
                 <th>Id Proiect</th>
                 <th>Tip actiune </th>
                 <th>Colaborator </th>
                 <th>Suma </th>
                 <th>Data </th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row-data">
                <td>{{ $istProj->id_proiect }}</td>
                <td>{{ $istProj->action_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ $istProj->colaborator_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $istProj->suma }}</td>
                <td>{{ $istProj->data }}</td>
               </tr>
          </table>
          </div>
            @empty
              <div class="card-body">
                 <h2>Nu au fost gasite inregistrari</h2>
               </div>
            @endforelse
```

Comment: In SQL it would be `SELECT * FROM Collabs WHERE id_project = 10`. I don't use Laravel, but I assume you can write the equivalent of that fairly easily using its ORM.

Comment: yes but i don t want exactly for id = 10. i want to display it dinamically. for example if i press view project with id 15, i want to display all collabs for id 15, an so on.

Comment: Show me your models, edit your first post, I think I have an idea of what you want to do

Comment: @KGG https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNHmK3lRj10

Comment: `i don t want exactly for id = 10. i want to display it dinamically`.  Yes of course, I understand that. You've got the ID in the URL parameter, so you can just take that and use it in the query (to replace the hard-coded value in my example)

Comment: @KGG i need to show only matched id's in that table. so for project view id 16 ( for example ) i need to show in that table only entries for Collabs with id 16 if exists.

Comment: @bigwall I understand your problem, but you really have a major design issue, I will write a solution for you, but I honestly URGE you to watch better youtube videos/tutorials on laravel eloquent & relationships, give me a moment.

Comment: why you say i have major design issue ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider reading and watching more videos on how relationships and eloquent works, I hope this below is a good reference for you to get started, please read carefully, and sorry I couldn't translate back to romanian, and to avoid any mistakes, I kept my code in english.

```
Caloboratori = Colaborators

Istoric Proiecte = Project History
id || auto_increment
project_id || bigInteger()
colaborator_id || bigInteger()

Proiecte = Project
id || auto_increment
```

**Project Model**

```
/* To load the history, we will be using hasMany relationship, because for each 
   project, we have lots of history, please read more on one-to-many relationships here
   https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

    Istoric Proiecte = Project History
        id || auto_increment
        project_id || bigInteger()
        colaborator_id || bigInteger()
*/
public function histories() {
    return $this->hasMany(ProjectHistory::class);    
}
```

**Project History Model**

```
//We will reverse the one-to-many relationship, with belongsTo here. | example: project_id
public function project() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}

//We will reverse the one-to-many relationship, with belongsTo here. | example: colaborator_id
public function colaborator() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Colaborator::class);
}
```

**Projects Controller:**

```
// Show a list of all projects
public function index() {  
    //Get all projects
    $projects = Project::all();

    //Load all of the project relationships that we will be using
    $projects->load('histories.colaborator');
    
    return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
 }

// Show a single project
public function show(Project $project) {  

    //Load all of the project relationships that we will be using
    $project->load('histories.colaborator');
    
    //Assign the loaded project history
    $histories = $project->histories;
    
    return view('projects.show', compact('project', 'histories'));
 }
```

**projects.index Blade**: in this blade, you can forloop thru all of your projects model, and assign them as `$project`, since we loaded the relationships earlier from the controller.

You can easily access the relationships using `$project->histories` then assign each history model to `$history`.

Then you can go one step inside of the history relationship and call the inner relationship of `colaborator` with `$history->colaborator`

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
    <p>Project id: {{ $project->id }}
    <p>Project name: {{ $project->name }}

    <h1>Project History list</h1>
    @foreach ($project->histories as $history)
       <ul>
            <li>ID: {{$history->id}}</li>
            <li>Name: {{$history->name}}</li>
            <li>Colaborator Name: {{$history->colaborator->name}}</li> 
    </ul>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**projects.show Blade**: in this blade, we have a single project, and you can forloop thru all of your history models, since we loaded the relationships from the controller.

We assigned the histories collection as `$histories` then assign each history model to `$history`

Then you can go one step inside the history relationship and call the inner relationship of `colaborator` with `$history->colaborator`

```
<p>Project name: {{ $project->name }}

<h1>Project History list</h1>
@foreach ($histories as $history)
    <ul>
        <li>ID: {{$history->id}}</li>
        <li>Name: {{$history->name}}</li>
        <li>Colaborator Name: {{$history->colaborator->name}}</li>
   </ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This would be a much better reference if you added some explanation

Comment: @ADyson I agree, I will do that for sure

Comment: thanks i guess but it seems pretty complicated, i don t know really how to put the code into my site lol

Comment: @bigwall I wrote lots of comments and explanations, I know it seems hard at first, and it really is, but if you do things step by step, and try it out, you will realize that it will make your life very simple in the future. Start by reading on the one-to-many relationships, once you understand that, come back to this answer, and try to implement it step by step. I promise you, you wont be disappointed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use model Collab, and within you have project relation , than you can use

```
Collab::query()
  ->with('project', function ($q) use ($id) {
    return $q->where('id', $id);
  })
  ->get();
```

Or you can use query builder as well

```
DB::table('collabs')
->select('collabs.*')
->join('projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'collabs.project_id')
->where('projects.id', $id)
->get();
```

Just adjust it according what you really need.

Comment: and how do i display them afterwards? because i had them in a foreach displayed in a table.

Comment: Result can be stored as $istoric and send it to your blade file ... You can use your current foreach loop, as long as all the column names are the same

Comment: can you explain a bit more of what all of that does? (speaking for 2nd example of yours), what ->select('collabs.*') does? what means .* ? it means all?

Comment: it is basic mysql query the same as SELECT collabs.* FROM collabs. ... collabs is the table name and * asterisk is wildcard, meaning return all columns from table collabs ... however for performance, best to return just the columns you will need, collabs.id, collabs.name .. etc